# NetworkActivity indicator in webview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

ive got a view based application containg a button clicking the button takes you to a web view..wat i want is the netwokActivityindicator to swirl..after finish loading of the web page i want the networkActivity indicator to disappear ...below is the code

```
-(IBAction)Button4

{

WebViewGive *newEnterNameController4 = [[WebViewGive alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewGive" 

bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newEnterNameController4 animated:YES];

[newEnterNameController4 release];


}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
    self.urlAddress1 = @"http://www.youtube.com/user/stevenandkeirabanks";

    self.url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress1];

    self.requestObj1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];

    [webViewAnnouncements loadRequest:requestObj1];

    }
```

if i m to use the network activity indicator below the

```
[webViewAnnouncements loadRequest:requestObj1];
```

I m jst getting a flickr and not the swrling of the activity indicator

Comment: @user652878 - please give time to format your question properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to add this line after you instantiate your UIWebView.

```
[webView setDelegate:self];
```

Now you will call webViewDidStartLoad: and the entire method should look like this.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}
```

You can stop the network activity indicator as follows -

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

Comment: i ve declared [webViewAnnouncements setDelegate:self];and [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;in view did load as mentioned... (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
still getting the flickr

Comment: @user652878 - iamsaurabhsharma

Comment: forgot 1 line: you've to add `<UIWebViewDelegate>` in .h